# Erro e MySQL: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are

Tags: ionic, ionic2, angular

Estou desenvolvendo um exemplo com IONIC mas está dando o erro:

```
ionic.bundle.js:19387 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: usuario in usuarios, Duplicate key: string:c, Duplicate value: c
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=usuario%20in%20usuarios&p1=string%3Ac&p2=c
    at ionic.bundle.js:7888
    at ngRepeatAction (ionic.bundle.js:32262)
    at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (ionic.bundle.js:21887)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:22020)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:22282)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:17439)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:17629)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:17570)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:19387(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:16350Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:22038Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:22282done @ ionic.bundle.js:17439completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:17629requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:17570
```

Já revisei várias vezes o código, já tentei mudar no ng-repeat com outras variáveis, mas ou o erro some ou não mostra os dados. O que pode ser?

Meu PHP:

```
    <?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objData = json_decode($data);

$dns = "mysql:host=mysql70.ramosdainformatica.com.br;dbname=ramosdainforma70";
$user = "usuario";
$pass = "senha";


$counter = $objData->counter;
$token = $objData->token;

try {   
    $con = new PDO($dns, $user, $pass);

    echo "Abriu con";

    if(!$con){
        echo "Não foi possivel conectar com Banco de Dados!";
    }
    if ($token === "1f3d2gs3f2fg3as2fdg3re2t1we46er45" && isset($token)) {  


        $query = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuario_app ORDER BY nome LIMIT '.$counter.', 5');
        $query->execute();


        $out = "[";
        while($result = $query->fetch()){
            if ($out != "[") {
                $out .= ",";
            }
            $out .= '{"cod_user: "'.$result["cod_user"].'",';
            $out .= '"nome": "'.$result["nome"].'",';
            $out .= '"pais": "'.$result["pais"].'",';
            $out .= '"cep": "'.$result["cep"].'"';
            $out .= '"logradouro": "'.$result["logradouro"].'",';
            $out .= '"complemento": "'.$result["complemento"].'",';
            $out .= '"bairro": "'.$result["bairro"].'",';
            $out .= '"cidade": "'.$result["cidade"].'"';
            $out .= '"estado": "'.$result["estado"].'",';
            $out .= '"celular": "'.$result["celular"].'",';
            $out .= '"email": "'.$result["email"].'",';
            $out .= '"senha": "'.$result["senha"].'"';
            $out .= '"data_cadastro": "'.$result["data_cadastro"].'",';
            $out .= '"latitude": "'.$result["latitude"].'",';
            $out .= '"longitude": "'.$result["longitude"].'"}';            

        }
        $out .= "]";
        echo $out; 


    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Erro: ". $e->getMessage();
};
```

Meu Controller:

```
    (function() {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("myApp").controller("initCtrl", function($scope, Data){
        $scope.home = "Usuários";
        $scope.perfil = "Perfil";

        $scope.usuarios = [];

        var getData = function(){
            var params = {
                counter:$scope.usuarios.length,
                token:"1f3d2gs3f2fg3as2fdg3re2t1we46er45",
            };

            Data.getData(params).success(function(data) {
                    $scope.usuarios = data;
            }).error(function(data) {
                console.log(data? data: "Não foi possível acessar ao banco de dados.");
            });


        };

        getData();



});
})();
```

Meu Service:

```
    (function(){
    "use strict";

    angular.module("myApp").value("Config", {

        getUrl: "http://www.ramosdainformatica.com.br/food/"
    });

    angular.module("myApp").service("Data", function($http, Config){
        //recuperação de dados
        this.getData = function(params){
            return $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: Config.getUrl + "apinhac.php",
                data: params,
                headers : {
                                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                            }
            });
        };


    });
})();
```

Minha lista HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{home}}">        

    <ion-content>
        <h1>{{home}}</h1>

        <ion-list ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios">

            <ion-item>
                <h1 class="assertive">{{usuario.nome}}</h1>
                <p>{{usuario.email}}</p>
            </ion-item>

        </ion-list>

    </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Já revisei várias vezes o código, já tentei mudar no ng-repeat com outras variáveis, mas ou o erro some ou não mostra os dados. O que pode ser?

Comment: Mano dei uma olhada no teu código aparentemente está tudo certo eu também trabalho com ionic e Angular Js ....A suspeita aqui é que deve estar faltando algum componente na tua aplicação que diz respeito ao Angular ou ao Ionic o que eu te aconselho é usar o INTEL XDK para trabalhar com Ionic lá vc não precisa instalar nada ou baixar alguma outra coisa vai te ficar bem mais fácil.

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que a propriedade que o angular está usando para ser a chave do seu loop, está se repetindo em alguma hora dentro da sua repetição. Tente usar outra chave, alguma que você tenha certeza que é única. Para isso use a expressão "track by" no seu ng-repeat.

Exemplo:

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios track by usuario.email">
```

Comment: Continua o erro.

Comment: No seu controler use console.log($scope.usuarios), cole o resultado em algum lugar escondendo os dados confidenciais e poste aqui por favor

Comment: @Ramos Verifique se tem alguma linha duplicada no seu array de usuários

Comment: Bom, pelo log tá acessando e lendo a tabela, pelo que vi não tem nada duplicado: Abriu con[{"cod_user: "1","nome": "usuario teste","pais": "Brasil","cep": "38300070""logradouro": "Rua Dezesseis, 1511","complemento": "","bairro": "Centro","cidade": "Ituiutaba""estado": "MG","celular": "3432610020","email": "ramos@ramosdainformatica.com.br","senha": "testeapp""data_cadastro": "2016-01-20 15:46:28","latitude": "","longitude": ""}]

Comment: tenta utilizar com track by usuario.cod_user  (repare que usuario não está no plural)

Comment: Continua o erro: <ion-list ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios track by usuario.cod_user">

Comment: Aliás, deu certo agora... mas não acessa mais o banco de dados... rs.

Comment: haha nossa que bizarro, está logando algo no console?

Comment: O console informa a mensagem que deixei: Não foi possível acessar ao banco de dados.

Comment: yntaxError: Unexpected number
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson (http://localhost:8100/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8883:14)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://localhost:8100/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16368:14)
    at http://localhost:8100/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16445:12
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8147:20)
    at transformData (http://localhost:8100/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16444:3)
    at transformResponse (http://localhost:8100/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17171:23)
    at processQueue

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.ramosdainformatica.com.br/food/apinhac.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Adicione isso no começo do arquivo apinhac.php: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Comment: Já está assim...

Comment: Você tá usando jsonp?

Answer (score 1):

Conforme dito na resposta do amigo Ziron, você deve ter certeza de que o elemento usado no `track by` seja único, que não se repita em outro elemento. Por exemplo, um `id` obtido do banco de dados.

Para isso usamos a opção `track by` para fazer um acompanhamento do loop baseado nesse index. MAS, se você não possui ou não sabe se possui um valor único, ou simplesmente não deseja utilizar um track baseado em suas propriedades, você pode utilizar o `$index` que é a posição do objeto dentro da array, ou seja, ele será sempre único, pois só existe um 1º elemento, um 2º elemento, etc..

Use assim: `ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios track by $index"`

Comment: Oi Celsom, agora o erro é: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.ramosdainformatica.com.br/food/apinhac.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.